# Pulley system with gear - torque

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I would like to ask, how can I calculate torque required for motor in this system if:

[image: System Model]

input pulley is smaller one (number of teeth= z1)
output is larger one (number of teeth= z2) with pinion (modul= m, number of teeth = z3) that moves system via rack

I know that gear ratio of pulleys is : z1/z2
then for torque between pulleys : z1/z2 = t1/t2 (t1: input torque t2: output)
torque for pinion : (m*z3)*F 
where F is force

So, if I calculate torque required for pinion, can I say, that it is torque of larger (output) pulley?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I have figured it out.

output torque should equal to torque provided by pinion, so its torque is the same as on larger pulley => if torque in pulley system is z1/z2= t1/t2 then t1= (t2*z1)/ z2 => t1 = (m*z3*F*z1)/ z2